# Change angular ui-grid's columns visibility

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I want to show/hide columns after the grid is rendered. Before i moved to the new ui-grid
I called to `toggleVisible()` but now it doesn't seem to work.
I tried to change the column def visibility(or any other property) like bellow

```
columnDefs[9].visible = false;
```

When I set the visibility on the column definition(before render) it does work, but after wards i cannot change it.

Answer (score 17):

Old question, but this works for me in 3.0.0-rc.20.  I'm guessing columnDefs needs to be in scope.

```
$scope.columnDefs = [ 
    { name: 'one' },
    { name: 'two', visible: false }
];

$scope.grid = {
    data: 'data',
    columnDefs: $scope.columnDefs
};

$scope.grid.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
};    

$scope.showColumnTwo = function() {
    $scope.columnDefs[1].visible = true;
    $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
};
```

Answer (score 11):

Just started working with `angular-ui-grid` so this might be not the best solution.

Try including the uiGrid api object and then invoking the `refersh` method on a `grid` object

```
...
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
};
....
columnDefs[9].visible = false;
$scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
```

Comment: Which ui-grid version are you using ? They probably have got a lot of changes since this answer was posted.

Comment: I'm using version 3.0

Comment: Try something like this to refresh in 3.0 `$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);` [API Doc](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:Grid#methods_notifydatachange)

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone was looking for a solution that didn't require you to create a columndDef.

```
 s.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      gridApi.core.registerColumnsProcessor(hideIdColumn);
      s.gridApi = gridApi;

      function hideIdColumn(columns){
          columns.forEach(function(column){
            if(column.field==='_id'){
              column.visible=false;
            }
          });
          return columns;
      }

    }
```

Just replace the column.field==='_id' part with your own condition.
Also don't forget to return the columns or you will not get any columns at all.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from **user3310980** was preferred when I saw it but there is very little documentation on the **registerColumnsProcessor** method. I found reference to his comment about using it without column definitions so I wanted to make it clear that you can certainly use this method **with** column defs. This provides for some interesting flexibility.

In this example, there are four columns that swap with four other columns determined by a toggle button. **`$ctrl.showDetails`** is `true` when sales columns should display and `false` when payment items should display.

In the column definitions, the **`onRefresh`** property is defined as a method to call for the column on grid refresh and the **`setVisibleColumns`** method is supplied to **`registerColumnsProcessor()`**. When the grid is refreshed, for each column, it will check the column definition in the **`colDef`** property and call the **`onRefresh`** method for each column that defines it, with **`this`** set to the column object.

```
/*--------------------------------------------*/
/* showPayments - Make payment items visible. */
/* showDetails  - Make sales items visible.   */
/*--------------------------------------------*/
var showPayments = function() { this.visible = !$ctrl.showDetails; };
var showDetails  = function() { this.visible =  $ctrl.showDetails; };

var columnDefs   =
  [
  { field: 'receiptDate',    displayName: 'Date',      width: 120, type: 'date', cellFilter: "date:'MM/dd/yyyy'", filterCellFiltered: true },
  { field: 'receiptNumber',  displayName: 'Rcpt No',   width:  60, type: 'number' },
  { field: 'receiptFrom',    displayName: 'From',      width: 185, type: 'string' },
  { field: 'paymentMethod',  displayName: 'Method',    width:  60, type: 'string', onRefresh: showPayments },
  { field: 'checkNumber',    displayName: 'No',        width:  60, type: 'string', onRefresh: showPayments },
  { field: 'checkName',      displayName: 'Name',      width: 185, type: 'string', onRefresh: showPayments },
  { field: 'paymentAmount',  displayName: 'Amount',    width:  70, type: 'string', onRefresh: showPayments },
  { field: 'description',    displayName: 'Desc',      width: 100, type: 'string', onRefresh: showDetails },
  { field: 'accountNumber',  displayName: 'Acct No',   width:  80, type: 'string', onRefresh: showDetails },
  { field: 'accountName',    displayName: 'Acct Name', width: 160, type: 'string', onRefresh: showDetails },
  { field: 'salesTotal',     displayName: 'Amount',    width:  70, type: 'string', onRefresh: showDetails }
  ];

/*----------------------------------------------------*/
/* Columns processor method called on grid refresh to */
/* call onRefresh' method for each column if defined. */
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
var setVisibleColumns = function(cols)
  {
  for (var i=0; i < cols.length; i++)
    if (cols[i].colDef.onRefresh)
      cols[i].colDef.onRefresh.call(cols[i]);
  return cols;
  };

/*----------------------------------*/
/* Callback to set grid API in      */
/* scope and add columns processor. */
/*----------------------------------*/
var onRegisterApi = function(api)
  {
  $ctrl.itemList.api = api;
  api.core.registerColumnsProcessor(setVisibleColumns);
  };

/*------------------------------*/
/* Configure receipt item grid. */
/*------------------------------*/
$ctrl.showDetails = false;
$ctrl.itemList    = 
  {
  columnDefs:                columnDefs,
  enableCellEdit:            false,
  enableColumnMenus:         false,
  enableFiltering:           false,
  enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.WHEN_NEEDED,
  enableVerticalScrollbar:   uiGridConstants.scrollbars.WHEN_NEEDED,
  data:                      [],
  onRegisterApi:             onRegisterApi
  };
```

When **`$ctrl.showDetails`** is changed, a simple refresh will swap the columns.

```
$ctrl.showDetails = !$ctrl.showDetails;
$ctrl.itemList.api.grid.refresh();
```

I hope this is helpful to someone.